# How to limit SQL Server Developer edition to Standard features

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I use

- Developer edition in my dev environment
- Standard edition in production

I want to make sure that in my dev env, indexed views will be treated the same way as in production.

Can I setup the Developer Edition to behave like Standard?

**[Edit]**
There is no such feature, but you can vote for it here:
[feedback.azure.com -> community -> SQL: Limit SQL Server Developer Edition features to a more restrictive edition (Standard Edition)](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e1761f1e-2797-ed11-a81b-000d3adb7ffd)

Comment: Can you use express in your dev environment? I don't think it is possible to turn off the Enterprise Edition features in developer edition like indexed view matching without `NOEXPAND` hint

Comment: There is no feature to disable enterprise behaviour in developer edition.

Comment: @MartinSmith: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16#using-noexpand) is written: _"Prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Service Pack 1, automatic use of an indexed view by the query optimizer is supported only in specific editions of SQL Server."_. Does that mean than in  2022 indexed view worksin Standard edition witout NOEXPAND?

Comment: @Liero - it sounds that way. I missed that change if so!

Comment: The short answer is no -- you need to test on actual editions. The longer answer is that since SQL Server 2016 SP1, as you've found, the base feature sets have been deliberately equalized between editions of SQL Server, so that (at least) it's less common to run into something that will plain not be supported on "lower" editions, it will just offer less performance/scalability. There's no substitute for testing on the actual edition, though.

Comment: I just tried on 2019 localdb and I'm not actually seeing automatic indexed view matching without `NOEXPAND` hint even on a massively expensive query. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJuS1.png

Comment: And in the discussion here Pedro Lopes specifically says this was not included so current state of the docs seems wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released